# Sorting a 2d JSON array by multiple attributes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How do I organise a list of (an array) arrays based on all the contents?

[image: screenshot of spreadsheet]

I am using a Google Sheets spreadsheet to generate image keys in an 11 x 11 grid. The keys are ordered based on their order in the spreadsheet. I want to group together keys with the most amount of "tag"s (see image) in common. I could do this via client-side js directly or organising the row order (in Sheets).

I want the tags to chain the entries together, listing first all entries with, e.g.: tags ["x","y","z"], then those with xya, then xja, then xjb, then xkb. So they flow into each other.

Is there a way to do this that won't take forever to load the keys? Or perhaps using indexing in some way?

Comment: I have the answer, it is 20 lines of code, but I don't know how to copy-paste it properly. Shall I post a screenshot of the code?

Comment: @SalmanA Yes please, unless https://pastebin.com/ works? :)

Comment: @SalmanA Any form is fine :)